# How do I share a PHP 5.4 server between OS X and VMWare?

Tags: macos, php, vmware-fusion

I'm running PHP 5.4 on OS X which allows me to set up a virtual server for any directory, using this Terminal command:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

This will then set up `http://localhost:8000` which works great, but what I would like to do is share this server with the instance of Windows that I have running through VMWare in order to test in Internet Explorer. I was wondering if this is possible and if it is, how do I go about setting it up? Currently trying to visit `http://localhost:8000` gives me 'This page cannot be displayed'.

I'd really appreciate any help that you can give me on this as I don't have much experience with virtual machines/networking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of saying you want to create a virtual server on `127.0.0.1` aka `localhost` provide your actual ip address or at the very least an internal intranet ip address like `192.168.1.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) I've found the answer. When OS X's file sharing is enabled, the system preferences gives you a message saying 'Computers on your local network can access your computer at: My-Mac.local'. After trying the IP address (which didn't work), I tried to setup `My-Mac.local:8000` instead, which worked! So for anyone who had this issue, simply use this terminal command:

```
php -S My-Mac.local:8000
```

Obviously replacing My-Mac.local with your computer's local name, and a different port if you'd like. :-)